# Store data with a dynamic key in a nested object using local storage

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local-storage

The below object is stored in the localStorage to mimic the server-side login/logout. I have logic in place to find the current user.

```
let defaultUsers = [
  { email: "test@test.com", password: "test123", favs: [] },
  { email: "dummy@dummy.com", password: "dummy123", favs: [] },
  { email: "example@example.com", password: "example123", favs: [] }
];
```

The idea is for current user i want to store favorite images [have logic in place to identify the clicked image out of a bunch of images] in the favs array of that particular user. i have written below logic but it doesn't work.

```
for (let usrs of Object.values(localStorage)) {
       JSON.parse(usrs).map(usr => {

       // imgURL is the url of image marked as favorite
       return usr.email === currentUsr ? localStorage.setItem(usr.favs, 
       imgURL)  : null;
      }
}
```

I really appreciate any help here.

Comment: How are you storing `defaultUsers` in localStorage? `Object.values(localStorage)` returns array of all the values in localStorage, not just users.

Comment: i'm storing it like `localStorage.setItem("defaultUsers", JSON.stringify(defaultUsers))`. Yes i understand Object.values(localStorage) returns array of all the values in localStorage if you notice i have used `map` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.values(localStorage)` returns an array of all values in local storage.

Since local storage `keys` and `values` are [always stored as strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), you'll get an array of strings.

In your code, you are iterating on this array and then using `JSON.parse()` to convert each string to an object. The resultant object is user object such as `{ email: "test@test.com", password: "test123", favs: [] }` which you can't apply `map()` method on 
because it is not an array.

You can instead do as shown below.

```
// Get users from localStorage.
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("defaultUsers"));

// Update image URL.
let modifiedUsers = users.map(user => {
  // Not copying the reference to prevent mutating original array.
  let favs = [...user.favs]; 

  if (user.email === currentUsr) {
    favs.push(imgURL);
  }

  return {
    ...user,
    "favs": favs
  };
});

// Update users in localStorage.
localStorage.setItem("defaultUsers", JSON.stringify(modifiedUsers));
```